# After downloading Android Studio, I have 1.9 GB or memory left, is that going to be a huge issue in the future?

Tags: chrome-book

I'm trying to learn programming. I found a course I'm interested in which covers basic programming, Kotlin, and uses Android Studio. I downloaded AS on my Chromebook (I have linux beta installed) and was left with 1.9 GB of memory left. I have no idea what that says about the path ahead of me. Is that going to turn into a massive roadblock?

I have enough money to get a very basic laptop, I even already know which one I'd get. Is that advisable in this case? I work full time, so it's a big deal if I have to devote time to hunting down the alternative, harder way of doing things. Although, if I learn something valuable from that, then it's worth it.

I used up 15GB and have a little bit less than two left.

Comment: What is the size of your drive? 1.9 GB is *very* little in the context of modern operating systems and will most likely lead to issues in the future. Did you perhaps download too many API levels?

Comment: answered up top